# MongoDB query with aggreate pipeline on $skip, $limit, $project & $lookup together

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql, aggregate

I want to implement `$skip, $limit, $project & $lookup` together on single aggregate via PHP

My following raw MongoDB query is working fine when hit from terminal and I want to implement this with PHP

```
db.getCollection("tbl_players").aggregate([

    {$skip: 10},
    {$limit: 10},
    {$project: {
        "fullname":1,
        "fullname_ar":1,
        "country.name":1,
        "country.name_ar":1,
        "country.ios2":1,
        "_id":1,
    }},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "tbl_countries",
        localField: "country_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "country"
    }}

])
```

---

I have tried multiple things to get it work, here is two of them

Here is output on my PHP Array which I am passing to [`MongoDB\Collection::aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-aggregate/) as `$pipeline`

```
array (size=4)
  '$skip' => int 10
  '$limit' => int 10
  '$project' => 
    array (size=6)
      '_id' => int 0
      'fullname' => int 1
      'fullname_ar' => int 1
      'country.name' => int 1
      'country.name_ar' => int 1
      'country.ios2' => int 1
  '$lookup' => 
    array (size=4)
      'from' => string 'tbl_countries' (length=13)
      'localField' => string 'country_id' (length=10)
      'foreignField' => string '_id' (length=3)
      'as' => string 'country' (length=7)
```

with above Array I got following error

> A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.

Follow array output

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      '$skip' => int 10
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      '$limit' => int 10
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      '$project' => 
        array (size=6)
          '_id' => int 0
          'fullname' => int 1
          'fullname_ar' => int 1
          'country.name' => int 1
          'country.name_ar' => int 1
          'country.ios2' => int 1
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      '$lookup' => 
        array (size=4)
          'from' => string 'tbl_countries' (length=13)
          'localField' => string 'country_id' (length=10)
          'foreignField' => string '_id' (length=3)
          'as' => string 'country' (length=7)
```

with above Array I got following error

> Each element of the 'pipeline' array must be an object

PHP Code to reproduce error

```
$more_where[]['$skip'] = 10;
$more_where[]['$limit'] = 10;
$more_where[]['$project'] = array(
                  '_id' => 0,
                  'fullname' => 1,
                  'fullname_ar' => 1,
                  'country.name' => 1,
                  'country.name_ar' => 1,
                  'country.ios2' => 1,
                );
$where['$lookup'] = array(
                  'from' => 'tbl_countries',
                  'localField' => 'country_id',
                  'foreignField' => '_id',
                  'as' => 'country',
                );


$collection->aggregate( array($where, $more_where) );
```

---

Here is versions of my PHP, MongoDB extension & MongoDB

PHP Version: 7.0.22

Driver version: 1.5.1

MongoDB version: 3.4.7

Comment: Please add the minimal PHP code to reproduce the error including versions of the database, php, and driver.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have added my versions.

Comment: Thanks, the first array is obviously wrong. The last one looks okay. If you  format it to valid php code I could try to reproduce it.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have updated my question and added code to reproduce the error

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$more_where = [];
$more_where[]['$skip'] = 10;
$more_where[]['$limit'] = 10;
$more_where[]['$project'] = array(
                  '_id' => 0,
                  'fullname' => 1,
                  'fullname_ar' => 1,
                  'country.name' => 1,
                  'country.name_ar' => 1,
                  'country.ios2' => 1,
                );
$more_where[]['$lookup'] = array(
                  'from' => 'tbl_countries',
                  'localField' => 'country_id',
                  'foreignField' => '_id',
                  'as' => 'country',
                );


$collection->aggregate( $more_where );
```

Comment: After implementing your solution I got this error.
`$pipeline is not a list (unexpected index: "skip")`
I got this error before while trying to resolve the issue.

Comment: if I add `array()` like `$collection->aggregate( array($more_where) );` I got again `A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`

Comment: Then you probably need to add a full mcve. I tested it with mongodb/mongodb 1.4 lib. Did you copy-paste it exactly or changed anything? The "unexpected index" suggests the later.

Comment: Yes copied exactly. I am using `mongodb/mongo-php-library 1.4.2`

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to believe. Are you sure you copied it exactly and didn't change the array? It works in `docker pull alexblex/so-52950517`. `cd /root`, then `php test.php` from within the container.